# If $|P|=p$, $|Q|=q$, $p, q$ primes, $p<q$ and $p|q-1$, then $Q\rtimes_{\varphi}P$ is nonabelian for nontrivial homomorphisms $\varphi: P\to Aut(Q)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra, $3^{rd}$ edition* by Dummit and Foote.

In Section 5.5, an example goes as follows:

Suppose $|G|=pq$ where $p, q$ are primes and $p<q$, $p|q-1$. Let $P\in Syl_p(G)$ and $Q\in Syl_q(G)$. Since $Aut(Q)$ is cyclic it contains a unique subgroup of order p, say $\langle\gamma\rangle$, and any homomorphism $\varphi: P\to Aut(Q)$ must map $y$ to a power of $\gamma$. There are therefore $p$ homomorphisms $\varphi_i: P\to Aut(Q)$ given by $\varphi_i(y)=\gamma^i$, $0\leq i\leq p-1$. **Each $\mathbf{\varphi_i}$ gives rise to a non-abelian group, $\mathbf{G_i}$, of order $\mathbf{pq}$.**

**My Question**: I understand that the group $G_i$ in the boldface texts refers to the semi-direct product $Q\rtimes_{\varphi_i}P$; I also know that there exists a non-abelian group of order $pq$. But how exactly does one see that $G_i$ is non-abelian?

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ and $Q$ are abelian and the operation in the group $G=Q\rtimes_\phi P$ is defined by the rule
$$
(a,b)\cdot(a',b')=(a\phi(b)(a'),bb'),
$$
where $a,a'\in Q$ and $b,b'\in P$,
then the group $G$ is abelian if and only if
$\phi(b)=1$ for all $b\in P$.

Compare
$$
(a,e)\cdot(e,b)=(a\phi(e)(e),b)=(a,b),
$$
$$
(e,b)\cdot(a,e)=(\phi(b)(a),b).
$$
It follows that all your groups $G_i$ are non-abelian.